# Lower bound for integrals like $\int_1^{t+1}e^{-\sqrt{s}}s^{-1}ds$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, integration

Let
$$I(t) = \int_{1}^{t+1}\exp\left\{-c\frac{s^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta}\right\}s^{-2\beta}ds,$$
where $c$ is some positive constant and $\beta\in(0, 1)$.

Since the integral $I(t)$ given above could not be given in closed form, I want a lower bound of $I(t)$.

What is a lower bound for $I(t)$ which is increasing in $t$?

Comment: What properties do you want the lower bound to have, in addition to being increasing?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers below?

Answer (score 4):

Let $b:=\beta$. By substitution
\begin{equation}
    x=c\frac{s^{1-b}}{1-b},
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
    I(t)=kJ\Big(c\frac{(t+1)^{1-b}}{1-b}\Big),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    k:=\Big(\frac{1-b}c\Big)^{\frac{1-2b}{1-b}},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    J(y):=\int_{y_0}^y e^{-x}x^{-B}\,dx,\quad y_0:=\frac c{1-b}>0,\quad B:=\frac{2b}{1-b}>0. 
\end{equation}

So, it remains to provide a lower bound on $J(y)$ which is increasing in $y\ge y_0$. Using the inequality $x^{-B}\ge(e/y_0)^B\,e^{-Bx/y_0}$ for $x>0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    J(y)&\ge \int_{y_0}^y e^{-x}(e/y_0)^B\,e^{-Bx/y_0}\,dx \\ 
    &=\Big(\frac e{y_0}\Big)^B\,\frac{y_0}{y_0+B}\,(e^{-y_0-B}-e^{-y-By/y_0}) =: H(y) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for $y\ge y_0$. Thus, we do have the lower bound $H(y)$ on $J(y)$ which is increasing in $y\ge y_0$. Also, $H(y_0)=0=J(y_0)$.

Comment: More detailed asymptotics follow from relating the integral to the incomplete Gamma function and using the expansion [DLMF 8.11.12](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.E12).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine : That asymptotics is only for large $z$. Also, it is only for the case when the two arguments of the incomplete gamma function are the same. Of course, there are other asymptotic expansions for the incomplete gamma function. However, here the request was for a lower bound, rather than for asymptotics.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I linked to the wrong formula. The correct reference is [DLMF 8.11.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.E2). They OP didn't specify what range of $t$ is most interesting. Knowing the asymptotics for large $t$ informs about what the growth rate of an "optimal" lower bound could be.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine : If there was a difficulty here, it was that we needed a reasonable bound, rather than asymptotics, and the bound had to be valid for all values of $c>0$, $\beta\in(0,1)$, and $t>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\b{\beta}$
Here is how I would write Iosif's answer, using the inequality $\ln u < u-1$.

Let
\begin{align}
u&=s^{1-\b}\\
du&=(1-\b)s^{-\b}ds\\
\frac{u^{-\b/(1-\b)}du}{1-\b}&=s^{-2\b}ds
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
I(t)
&= \int_{1}^{t+1}\exp\left[-c\frac{s^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta}\right]s^{-2\beta}ds\\[1.5ex]
&= \int_{1}^{(1+t)^{1-b}}\exp\left[\frac{-cu}{1-\beta}\right]\frac{u^{-\b/(1-\b)}du}{1-\b}\\[1.5ex]
&= \frac{1}{1-\b}\int_{1}^{(1+t)^{1-\b}}\exp\left[\frac{-cu-\b\ln u}{1-\beta}\right]du\\[1.5ex]
&\ge \frac{1}{1-\b}\int_{1}^{(1+t)^{1-\b}}\exp\left[\frac{-cu-\b(u-1)}{1-\beta}\right]du\\[1.5ex]
&=\frac{e^{\b/(1-\beta)}}{-(\b+c)}\,\large{e^{au}\Big|_1^{(1+t)^{1-\b}}}\\[1.5ex]
&=\frac{e^{\b/(1-\beta)}}{\b+c}\large{\left(
e^{a}-
e^{a(1+t)^{1-\b}}
\right)}\\[1.5ex]
\end{align}
where $a=-(\b+c)/(1-\b)$.
This bound agrees with $I(t)$ when $t=0$, and is indeed increasing with $t$.